# PHP custom chat, coding a block function

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried to build a Block function without any luck, my SQL skills are not as good as I hoped they would be in this case.

I have one table called "messages" and one table called "blocks"
Now, there's 1 file syncing everything to the Chat, what I'm trying to do is IF user 1 has blocked user 2 than user 1's messages should never reach user 2 and user 2's message should not reach user 1. In short term, if you block someone you can't speak to him/her and him/her can't speak to you!

```
"blocks" table:
id bigint(20)
user_id tinyint(20)
block_id tinyint(20)

"messages" table:
id bigint(20)
timestamp datetime
dest_type varchar(255)
dest_id bigint(20)
source_type varchar(255)
source_id bigint(20)
message_type varchar(255)
message text
```

in "blocks" user_id is the owners id of the block row.
and block_id is the id that the owner wants to block.
IF `"messages.source_id = blocks.block_id OR messages.block_id = blocks.user_id"`
THAN dont let the message get trough. I understand that asking someone to code this for me is quite rude but I'm asking, can anyone give this a shot?

here's the sync.php file:
http://pastebin.com/8iiSCXGS

Big thanks!

Comment: So the messages.source_id is the ID of the message creator? Is this a private messaging operation? From the creator's point of view, if they have blocked someone, you want to restrict them being available in the form where you create the message. From the point of view of the blocked user, do you want them to know if they've been blocked?

Comment: Hello, yes that's correct! I want sync.php to NOT pic up messages from users that have blocked me and that I have blocked. All blocks are stored in blocks table as you can see above. In private chat I have fixed the Block feature! But in the open room where everyone speaks to one another the sync.php file sends all messages between the users and that's why sync.php has to check the blocks table to see if it should pick up the message or not, this is very complicated (atleast to me...)

Comment: Ok, so it would still store the messages in the database but wouldn't show them. I believe this could be achieved by joining the tables together.

Comment: Yes, the message will be sent to send.php which will store them, sync.php then downloads them and shows them to the right user. How can we join them together? I suck at that tbh :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't delved very deeply into your code, but perhaps this will help.

Let's start with a reduced database structure as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `blocks` (
  `id`            BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `user_id`       INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `block_id`      INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO `blocks` (`user_id`,`block_id`) VALUES
  (1,2),(3,4),(2,1);

CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id`            BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `author_id`     BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `message`       TEXT NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO `messages` (`author_id`,`message`) VALUES
  (1,"Message from user #1, who has a mutual block in place with user #2"),
  (2,"Message from user #2, who has a mutual block in place with user #1"),
  (3,"Message from user #3, who has blocked user #4"),
  (4,"Message from user #4, who has been blocked by user #3"),
  (5,"Message from user #5, who takes no part in all this blocking business");
```

Now let's suppose user `$n` visits the website (where 1≤`$n`≤5). To figure out which messages can be displayed, we need to perform a LEFT JOIN of the `messages` and `blocks` tables — i.e., we want to consider every row of `messages` together with any row of `blocks` that contains relevant information (specifically, where the author of the message has blocked user `$n`, or has been blocked by user `$n`). If `$n`=1, we have the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages`
  LEFT JOIN `blocks`
    ON (`author_id`=`block_id` AND `user_id`=1)
    OR (`author_id`=`user_id` AND `block_id`=1);
```

Here's the result of that query:

```
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+----------+
| id | author_id | message                                                               | id   | user_id | block_id |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+----------+
|  1 |         1 | Message from user #1, who has a mutual block in place with user #2    | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |
|  2 |         2 | Message from user #2, who has a mutual block in place with user #1    |    1 |       1 |        2 |
|  2 |         2 | Message from user #2, who has a mutual block in place with user #1    |    3 |       2 |        1 |
|  3 |         3 | Message from user #3, who has blocked user #4                         | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |
|  4 |         4 | Message from user #4, who has been blocked by user #3                 | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |
|  5 |         5 | Message from user #5, who takes no part in all this blocking business | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, the rows we want are the ones where the last three columns are NULL, which means there is no blocking rule affecting the display of this particular message to this particular user. So to extract these messages, we simply add `WHERE block_id IS NULL` to the end of the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages`
  LEFT JOIN `blocks`
    ON (`author_id`=`block_id` AND `user_id`=1)
    OR (`author_id`=`user_id` AND `block_id`=1)
  WHERE `block_id` IS NULL;
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+----------+
| id | author_id | message                                                               | id   | user_id | block_id |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+----------+
|  1 |         1 | Message from user #1, who has a mutual block in place with user #2    | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |
|  3 |         3 | Message from user #3, who has blocked user #4                         | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |
|  4 |         4 | Message from user #4, who has been blocked by user #3                 | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |
|  5 |         5 | Message from user #5, who takes no part in all this blocking business | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

If you substitute different user IDs into this query, you should get the results you're after.

Comment: I will check this out when I wake up tomorrow!

Comment: Thank you squeamish ossifrage this helped me to solve the problem :D

Comment: You're welcome. Can I just add that if you want to implement this sort of "ignore" system on a public website, make sure that the moderators can still see messages from people who are ignoring them, otherwise a spammer could put everyone on ignore and then fill the site with linkspam and other garbage without ever being detected.

Comment: Yeh, I have already made sure that blocking moderators are not possible.